# Generate a fake date between two date in Python data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame called "test" as follows, I would like to generate a random date between this two date.

```
id       first_month        last_month
PT1      2011-06-01         2019-10-01
PT3      2020-09-01         2022-06-01
```

```
import random
test["random_date"] = test.first_month_active + (test.last_month_active - start) * random.random()
```

I tried with this code but the error is :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'TimedeltaArray' and 'datetime.date'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) of subtracted values, multiple by [`numpy.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) and add timedeltas to original `first_month` column:

```
df['first_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['first_month'])
df['last_month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['last_month'])

n = df['last_month'].sub(df['first_month']).dt.days * np.random.uniform(size=len(df))

df["random_date"] = df["first_month"] + pd.to_timedelta(n.astype(int), 'D')
print (df)
    id first_month last_month random_date
0  PT1  2011-06-01 2019-10-01  2016-06-15
1  PT3  2020-09-01 2022-06-01  2021-08-17
```

**Performance**:

```
#20k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [183]: %%timeit
     ...: n = df['last_month'].sub(df['first_month']).dt.days * np.random.uniform(size=len(df))
     ...: 
     ...: df["random_date"] = df["first_month"] + pd.to_timedelta(n.astype(int), 'D')
     ...: 
2.75 ms ± 85.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [185]: %%timeit
     ...: df['random_date'] = [np.random.choice(pd.date_range(first, last), 1)[0]
     ...:                      for first, last in zip(df['first_month'], df['last_month'])]
     ...:                      
3.87 s ± 531 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option using a list comprehension with [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
from random import sample

df['random_date'] = [np.random.choice(pd.date_range(first, last), 1)[0]
                     for first, last in zip(df['first_month'], df['last_month'])]
```

Output:

```
    id first_month  last_month random_date
0  PT1  2011-06-01  2019-10-01  2019-03-15
1  PT3  2020-09-01  2022-06-01  2020-12-21
```